# How to get started in designing games

Tags: game-engine

How can i design games in a more interactive and in efficient. What steps are required to design a game. What tools are used in designing games?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE!  We are geared towards more specific questions here though, you would probably get more luck with this kind of question over at [BlenderArtists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/).  Once you have some specific problems or questions this is the place to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ***many*** ways to build games, and you have almost *unlimited* options, it's just up to **you** to pick.

***Blender*** has it's own *built-in* game engine, but there are other free ones, which many people believe to have superior features, such as [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) and [Unity 3D](https://unity3d.com/). You may consider trying one of these options, as they are more widely used.

**However**, the Blender Game Engine is ***quickly advancing***, and it takes less knowledge of *importing/exporting* models, and complex graphic knowledge in general, than the other two. *Because we are on a **Blender** forum, I will focus on Blender here.*

- A *good* way to **get started**, is by learning from some simple *"project tutorials"*. [Here are some good ones by Born CG.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLda3VoSoc_TSS7ht07sCt8zDCyAenOG6i)
- If you don't know much about coding, and still think making games is for you, now is a good time to **learn some code**. I recommend [Python](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python), as it works well with many programs, including Blender.
- *Now that you know some **code**,* you can learn how to [integrate that code into Blender](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/python-scripting/), or other software. *Here's another [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cklrL9LD3XI&list=PLE2B41D3C37C16EEF)*.
- Now that you know a little bit about it, you can [join a project.](http://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?53-Volunteer-Work) This can help you to learn other skills, and get in the community. (*before you do, you may want to [consider](https://soundcloud.com/andrew-price/episode-5-why-i-refuse-all) how long you are willing to spend on it, so you don't get caught up.* A good project that uses Unity and is going somewhere, [is here.](https://twitter.com/psychic_studios))

So consider it... and see what you come up with. :)